# Chai deep.equal failing on comparison of {} to promise instance

Tags: javascript, testing, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, chai

Trying to understand why `deep.equal` is still passing when the two objects are very different:

```
it.only('fetches a footer', () => {
  const fetchedAction = { type: FETCH_FOOTER, payload: {} };
  mockGet(host, 'footer.json', null, null);

  const action = fetchFooter();
  expect(action).to.deep.equal(fetchedAction);
});
```

So here are the values being compared for action vs. fetchedAction:

[image]

Notice how for the `payload` property they're not the same type of object.  Then how come my expect isn't failing if that's the case?

Related (yea I read this but still not sure why simply `deep.equal` wouldn't fail here): http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep

Answer (score 0):

The docs you've linked to at http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_deep point to https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql#rules which explains all this:

- Strict equality for non-traversable nodes according to Object.is:

  - `eql(NaN, NaN).should.be.true;`
  - `eql(-0, +0).should.be.false;`
- All own and inherited enumerable properties are considered:

  - `eql(Object.create({ foo: { a: 1 } }), Object.create({ foo: { a: 1 } })).should.be.true;`
  - `eql(Object.create({ foo: { a: 1 } }), Object.create({ foo: { a: 2 } })).should.be.false;`
- Arguments are not Arrays:

  - `eql([], arguments).should.be.false;`
  - `eql([], Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)).should.be.true;`
- Error objects are compared by reference (see chaijs/chai/issues/608):

  - `eql(new Error('msg'), new Error('msg')).should.be.false;`
  - `var err = new Error('msg'); eql(err, err).should.be.true;`

So given your example objects, the only rule that applies is

> All own and inherited enumerable properties are considered

and that is the key. Your two objects have the same enumerable properties. Both of these loops print nothing:

```
for (var prop in {}) console.log(prop);
```

and

```
for (var prop in Promise.resolve({key: 'value'})) console.log(prop);
```

The properties in square brackets printed by the promise are engine-specific internal data that are not object properties.

Comment: but I'm not resolving the promise in my test...so I guess if I want to check object types, hmm how would I do that then.  Promise vs. {} are not the same "type" of objects.  So what _would_ be the proper way to test this?

Comment: It's not related to whether the promise is resolved or not, it's that a promise object and an empty object both compare as equal. If you want to test that the _result_ of the promise is equal to something, you'd have to do `.then` and do your `expect` inside there with the promise resolution value.

Comment: I thought the same, but [the code](https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql/blob/master/index.js#L183) also checks for the [type](https://github.com/chaijs/deep-eql/blob/master/index.js#L183) of the objects to be the same, and should recognise a native `Promise`

Comment: Hmm, @PositiveGuy are you using Babel and if so, what plugins are you using?

Comment: And are you using `babel-polyfill`?